# Skip dependencies with rosdep install?

Tags: rosdep, ros-hydro, rosdep-install, ubuntu, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I've built a number of ros installations on ubuntu for armhf from source, from 12.04 to 14.04 however when running rosdep for package dependencies:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
```

I usually hit problems as some dependencies (sbcl, yaml-cpp to name a few) are not built for armhf. I can build and install these from source however rosdep is usually not satisfied and can't find or substitute the built packages. Additionally its pretty hard to find the source packages that depend on these so that the package.xml may be modified.

Is there some way to stop rosdep from searching for particular packages or detect installations that didn't come from apt-get or as dpkg or help it find the installed dependency?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188398/skip-dependencies-with-rosdep-install?/) by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1493 on 2014-07-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdep has the `-r` option to keep going if packages can't be found, and the `--skip-keys` option which makes it assume that packages are already installed.

For more details, see the built-in help: `rosdep -h`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2014-07-31**:
That's great and what I needed. Even provided a convenient list of missed dependencies at the end. Thanks very much.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-06-16**:
This is an example of skipping gazebo and rviz (the keys are the same as what is in a package.xml entries, not the name of the package to be installed, not `gazebo11` and `ros-noetic-rviz` in this case)

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --skip-keys="gazebo rviz" -r -s
```